# how could I find the area of the intersection of line and contour

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

the blue pen is the contour

and the red pen is the straight line

how could I find the two areas of the intersection of line and contour

Now, I can get the contour area by

`area = cv2.contourArea(np.array( [ [i] for i in blue_points  ]  ))`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple but perhaps not the most efficient way would be to use `cv.drawContours` and `cv.line` to create two images: one with the contour of the blob and one with the contour of the line. Then `cv.bitwise_and` them together, and any point that is still positive will be points of intersection.

Answer (score 1):

`Shapely` [library](https://pypi.org/project/shapely/) makes it quick.

Assuming you have points of contour and line:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString

poly = Polygon([(5,5), (10,10), (10,0)])
a = LineString([(0, 0), (8, 8)])
print(a.intersects(poly))
```

There are options to speed up the code. Not checked.